# Pointer notation in C

Tags: c, pointers

I know more C++ than C.  Does C use -> for pointers, or is that only used in C++?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is used in both languages.

Answer (score 17):

The `->` operator is part of standard C.

`(expression)->identifier` is equivalent to `(*expression).identifier` - obviously, for this to be valid, `expression` must have a type of pointer to structure or pointer to union.